# Pass canvas.toDataURL return to a div

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I try to capture the image of Streetview panorama that appear into a Google map infowindow. I have created a button that call function captureImage() but I struggle to pass the var = img variable it returns to the HTML .

I think there is problem with the variable "contentString" and "content" that are local. Shall I write captureImage() function into initialize() ? thanks you.

My code is as follow :

```
function initialize() {

//code here

    var contentString = '<input type="button" value="Grab this picture" onClick="captureImage()" /> <div id="content" style="width:300px;height:400px;"></div>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

//code here

}

function captureImage()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("content");
    var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');

}
```

HTML :

```
    <div id="dialog" title="Image box">
        <p>Here is the image from Streetview :</p>
                    <img scr=""></img>
    </div>
```

Comment: it's impossible to capture from div. Things just don't work this way.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that. The alternative would be to request the Google Map Image API. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/

Comment: Another methode would be to render the HTML content into a canvas, then export 'canvas' element into JPEG with 'canvas.toDataURL("image/png");'.

Comment: It is possible, but it could be very hard. You will need some help form some libs.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier I think to set directly the `<img>`'s src with:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=<width>x<height>&location=lat,%20lng&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&sensor=false`